# Play framework compilation time worth the development effort?

Tags: playframework

I got to proudly deploy a helloworld project on Java's Play framework. Before I decide to consider it the primary framework for the project I want to build, I decided to play around. I'm worried about one thing among a few:

1. Hot compilation is excellent, but it's very slow. A small change in the string triggers entire project re-compilation which takes ~ 30 seconds. 
   Compared to Python Django, this is very slow. I could just change whatever I want including the system calls, and it'll just work on a refresh as if it doesn't matter to the framework what was changed.

Am I missing something here about Play? I'm worried about development times. If every time I add something and have to wait ~ 30 seconds to test it, that's a huge blow. But I'm sure these were definitely the considerations while building this shiny framework.
Appreciate your thoughts! Please enlighten and let me Play! :)

Comment: That's definitely something wrong... small changes are hot-reloaded within less than 1 second. Reloading times may increase when your project grows and includes more and more dependencies, but hello world is not a case for that

Comment: can you let me know your development environment? I'm using eclipse IDE and command prompt for activator, and find it pretty slow on hot reload.

Comment: Idea Ultimate, Mac OS El Capitan, i5, you can also check if it's IDE's problem, just run your app from the terminal (mac/linux) cmd (win) with command like `./activator ~run` and then use some simple editor (notepad or smtg) to edit the files and observe if it still hot-reloads slowly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're comparing between a Java framework and Python. So, yes, hot compilation does take longer than a Django-based restart. But compared to other Java frameworks, like Spring, I find this benefit to be huge.

Second, what hardware/platform are you on? I've tried Play under these circumstances:

**(1) Code on Eclipse, Play server run via `activator run` in command prompt**
Refresh takes about 8-10 seconds at 10KLOC project size.

**(2) Code in IntelliJ Ultimate, Play server run within IntelliJ**
Refresh takes 1 second for a small change at 20KLOC project size.

The 8-10 second reload time of the first case did not bother me. And when I started using IntelliJ, I was really happy with the speed boost.

**In conclusion:**
(1) I love Play's hot reload
(2) Using IntelliJ Ultimate made it even better (note: the free version does not support Play)

**Note**: I am not affiliated with Play Framework or IntelliJ in any way, except for being a happy first-time user.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, there's some delight to know refresh time greatly reduced with IntelliJ, will give it a try.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I am using the Ultimate edition. The free edition does not support Play.

Comment: It is indeed very fast with the IntelliJ, mostly because of the SBT incremental compiler!